# C# Manipulate pdf document using ITextSharp in order to place 2 fields in the same PDF page and at the beginning of the page

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have a PDF file and I am trying to move two fields (let's say f1 and f2) within PDF document to the same page (because sometimes, depending on the pdf content, f1 and f2 are printed within pdf file in different pages). So I am using ITextSharp to manipulate the pdf and create a new one.

I need to show both fields in the same page of the pdf document. f1 field should always be shown in the pdf above f2 field, and both fields should appear in the same pdf page.

So if for example f2 field is printed in page 2 of the pdf and f1 field is printed in page 1, then I need to manipulate the pdf using ITextSharp to print both, fields f1 and f2, in page 2 and f1 field above f2 field. So how can I do this using ITextSharp?

Comment: Of course you can move the fields to the same page. But of course you need more exact coordinates than merely "f1 above f2".

Comment: @mkl and if I want to move both fields to the top of a page, in this case, according to the example, to page 2, how can i do this? could you provide a snippet code? The exact coordinates would be the top left of the new page, starting from this coordinate I would like to place field f1 and under it f2.

Comment: Please share an example file; this allows to test a code snippet beforehand.